# Cell get unselected without deselect command

Tags: php, objective-c, no-op

Usually my typical didselectrowatindexpath is like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    BGUIBusinessCellForDisplay * cellBiz = (BGUIBusinessCellForDisplay *) cell;
    [BGDetailBusinessViewController detailButtonPressed:cellBiz.biz withNavController:self.navigationController];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

So if a row is selectec, open a new window or something. Then quickly deselect the row. Not deselecting the row means when we got back the row previously selected will still be there.

However if I check at my past codes, I saw that the row is succesfully deselected even though I didn't call deselect at all

I put a trap everywhere to track where and when the row is deselected:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

...

PO(self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow); //always show null here
while(false);
```

}

Turns out by viewDidAppear, say after I return from detail, the self.tablevView.indexPathForSelectedRow is already null. So the row is already deselected but when and where?

I put more trap on obvious places

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    while (false);//breakpoint here never called
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    while (false); //breakpoint here never called 
}
```

None of those are ever called.

I gave up.

Not biggy right now but this puzzles me to no end

This is the full didSelectRowForIndexPath so you can verify that there is no desellect command there

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[BGUIBusinessCellForDisplay class]])
    {
        BGUIBusinessCellForDisplay * cellBiz = (BGUIBusinessCellForDisplay *) cell;
        [BGDetailBusinessViewController detailButtonPressed:cellBiz.biz withNavController:self.navigationController];
    }
    else if ([cell isKindOfClass:[BGAddMoreBusiness class]])
    {
        BGBusinessEditViewController * editBusiness = [[BGBusinessEditViewController alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController SafelyPushController:editBusiness];
    }
    PO(self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow); //not null here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That is the default behaviour of `UITableViewController`, see the documentation of `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear`:

> The default value of this property is `YES`. When `YES`, the table view
>   controller clears the table’s current selection when it receives a
>   `viewWillAppear:` message. Setting this property to `NO` preserves the
>   selection.

Comment: I am using tableView with UIViewController not UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Update: by `viewWillAppear` row is still selected. by `viewDidAppear`, it no longer is. Between them there is `[table reload]`. Looks like `[table reload]` deselect the row.